# .SQLiteException: no such table: tblPhong (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR): , while compiling: SELECT * FROM tblPhong

Tags: android, sqlite

It seems i don't have tblPhong table in my database, maybe my createTable() isn't correct, but it's correct on another app i built, i can't find the mistake of my code, pls help me !

This is my PhongTroDB class

```
public class PhongTroDB {


    String dbName = "phongtro.db";
    Context context;
    SQLiteDatabase db;

    public PhongTroDB(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }
    public SQLiteDatabase openDB(){
        return context.openOrCreateDatabase(dbName,Context.MODE_PRIVATE,null);
    }
    public void createTable(){
        String sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tblPhong(" +
                "MAPHONG INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," +
                "TANG INTEGER," +
                "DIENTICH INTEGER," +
                "GIATIEN INTEGER," +
                "MOTA TEXT)";
        db = openDB();
        db.execSQL(sql);
        db.close();
    }


    public int countPhong(){
        String sql = "SELECT * FROM tblPhong";
        db = openDB();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(sql,null);
        int count = cursor.getCount();
        return count;
    }

    public void insertPhong(int tang, int dienTich, int giaTien, String mota){
        db = openDB();
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put("TANG",tang);
        cv.put("DIENTICH",dienTich);
        cv.put("GIATIEN", giaTien);
        cv.put("MOTA",mota);
        db.insert("tblPhong",null,cv);
        db.close();
    }

    //Select
    //Select *
    public ArrayList<PhongTro> getPhongTro(){
        ArrayList<PhongTro> tmp = new ArrayList<>();
        String sql = "SELECT * FROM tblPhong";
        db = openDB();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(sql, null);
        while (cursor.moveToNext()){
            int maPhong = cursor.getInt(0);
            int tang = cursor.getInt(1);
            int dienTich = cursor.getInt(2);
            int giaTien = cursor.getInt(3);
            String mota = cursor.getString(4);
            PhongTro phongtro = new PhongTro(maPhong,tang,dienTich,giaTien,mota);
            tmp.add(phongtro);
        }
        db.close();
        return tmp;
    }


}
```

This is class Data, Where i put data to my database

```
public class Data extends Application {
    PhongTroDB phongTroDB;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        phongTroDB = new PhongTroDB(this);
        phongTroDB.createTable();
        if (phongTroDB.countPhong() == 0){
            phongTroDB.insertPhong(1,6,3000000,"Phòng thoáng mát, có ban công, full nội thất");
            phongTroDB.insertPhong(1,5,2800000,"Phòng thoáng mát, có cửa sổ, có tủ lạnh");
            phongTroDB.insertPhong(1,5,2800000,"Có cửa sổ, tủ lạnh, máy giặt");
            phongTroDB.insertPhong(2,7,3200000,"Phòng thoáng mát, có ban công, view sông, full nội thất");
            phongTroDB.insertPhong(2,7,3200000,"Phòng thoáng mát, có ban công, view sông,full nội thất");
            phongTroDB.insertPhong(2,7,3200000,"Phòng thoáng mát, có ban công, view sông,full nội thất");
            phongTroDB.insertPhong(3,8,3500000,"Phòng thoáng mát, có ban công, view LandMark81,full nội thất");
            phongTroDB.insertPhong(3,8,3500000,"Phòng thoáng mát, có ban công, View LandMark81,full nội thất");
        }
    }
}
```

This is my adapter

```
public class PhongTroAdapter extends  RecyclerView.Adapter<PhongTroAdapter.PhongTroVH>{

    Context context;
    ArrayList<PhongTro> lstPhong;

    public PhongTroAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<PhongTro> lstPhong) {
        this.context = context;
        this.lstPhong = lstPhong;
    }


    @NonNull
    @Override
    public PhongTroVH onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.cardview,parent,false);
        return new PhongTroVH(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull PhongTroVH holder, int position) {
        PhongTro phongtro = lstPhong.get(position);
        if(phongtro == null){
            return;
        }
        holder.tvPhong.setText(phongtro.getMaphong());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        if(lstPhong != null){
            return lstPhong.size();
        }
        return 0;
    }



    public class PhongTroVH extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        TextView tvPhong;
        public PhongTroVH(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            tvPhong = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvPhong);
        }
    }
}
```

This is my MainActivity, I use RecyclerView GridLayout

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    RecyclerView rvPhong;
    ArrayList<PhongTro> lstPhong;

    PhongTroAdapter phongTroAdapter;
    PhongTroDB phongTroDB;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        phongTroDB = new PhongTroDB(this);

        rvPhong = findViewById(R.id.rvPhong);

        lstPhong = phongTroDB.getPhongTro();

        phongTroAdapter = new PhongTroAdapter(this,lstPhong);

        GridLayoutManager gridLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(this, 2);
        rvPhong.setLayoutManager(gridLayoutManager);

        rvPhong.setAdapter(phongTroAdapter);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't see where your 'Data' class is being used to then call createTable() but in any case why not change PhongTroDB class to extend SQLiteOpenHelper and implement onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) (and onUpgrade etc.) and put your table creation there.